# Generator question

Tags: electrical, generator

Is it possible to use my 50a plug off the portable generator to run my main panel with interlock kit of course  and the 30a plug off of a  manual transfer switch. My house is electric heat and I would want to run my well pump and as well the hot water heater. And 30a to plugs around the house. Is such application to code.

Comment: Usually generators will give the option to use the 50 amp receptacle or the 30 amp receptacle.  Seldom you can use both together.  Good chance you do not even get the full 50 amps, maybe 40 or 45.  Electric heat might be too much for it.  Edit the size of generator into the question and type of electric heat.  Heat pumps much better for generators than electric resistance heat.

Comment: So the generator I was looking to buy was the generac 18000efi and my heat is electric baseboard heat

Comment: You probably can use both receptacles together at that size.  will give you 75 amps.  Can you add up just the breakers that are used for heat?

Comment: 2 30a and 2 20a

Comment: Is there a reason you're looking at running toaster heat off a generator? (even a HWH off a generator is pushing it mildly)

Comment: I take it you have no utility gas or LP storage?  Because the weight and $/kW of this beast are through the roof.  And the emergency plan is to haul out a 450lb "portable" generator, hook up two inlets, and at the power levels you are planning, to feed it 2.5 gallons of fuel **per hour**.    What's the plan for *that*?  Maybe you need a propane tank and a wholly different approach?  Or a couple of space heaters and a kettle for hot water?  Then you can use a smaller generator with simple wiring.

Answer (score 4):

> with interlock kit of course and the 30a plug off of a manual transfer switch

Transfer switches are obsolete and dangerous products fraught with problems. They skate by on a UL listing they got in the 1960s, but they cannot be responsibly used in any modern panel.  How they handle neutral is particularly bad, and a root of their problems.

### You can't connect neutral twice like that

Absolutely not. You cannot feed two panels or two loads with the same generator, because that would entail parallel/redundant neutral connections.

There are two ways to beat this.  #1 is - a generator of that size is designed to be hard-wired into a building, so hard-wire a single connection into a generator interlock.  Interlocks can go as high as 125A, so that's not a problem.

#2, on your second (and any further) connections, switch neutral using a costly 3-pole "Frankenstein style" knife switch.   *However in your case, this is easier*.

### A special no-neutral panel, though!

Of course it sounds like your major loads (well pump, water heater and electric baseboard heat) are 240V-only loads which do not require neutral.  As such, you could install a 240V-only subpanel, place those 240V-only loads (no neutral) in that, and use a second "generator interlock" in that panel, feeding a NEMA 6-50 type inlet (which does not have neutral).   This satisfies the "must switch neutral on second connection" rule because neutral doesn't exist at all.

Special care should be used in this 240V-only panel to keep people from slapping 120V loads in there.  An accessory ground bar should be purchased and all ground loads taken to the ground bar.  Leave the neutral bar completely and conspicuously unused, with nothing connecting to it, and remove the neutral-ground bond.

(The tradesman's shortcut is normally to re-task the neutral bar to be the ground bar, but then, this is confusing to later installers who see the populated neutral bar, and confuse it for a neutral bar - gosh, can you blame them?  So no, don't do that. Pay for the accessory ground bar, conspicuously not using the neutral bar.  Since the N-G bond is pulled, if someone does attach a neutral there, it won't work!

I would probably run the 50A port into the special no-neutral subpanel, and the 30A port into the rest of the house.

Your inlet needs to be NEMA 6-50 type (no neutral) however you can use a 6-50 to 14-50 cheater to get into the generator socket - that particular cheater is no problem to be UL-Listed, since the NEMA 6 doesn't need the neutral.

### Check your Load Calculation on those loads

> My heat is two 30a and two 20a breakers.

Yeah, you'll want to run a Load Calculation on the loads you intend to place on generator.  I'm seeing, well, the heaters will be less than the breakers but it's making me nervous that there's 100A of breakers there.  So be careful here.

Comment: OP will need to confirm if it is two separate double pole 30 plus two separate double pole 20 breakers or just a single double pole 30 and 20 breaker.  Hope you understand what I am saying.

Comment: Saying #1 the generator can be hard wired is reasonable, but this generator is not reasonable and it can't!  It can only achieve it's rating by maxing out both 240V outlets and it's also a huge stretch to call it portable at 450 lbs.  240V panel is clever idea.